# Не работает генерация .pdf на сервере с внешнего ip

Tags: c#, windows

На том же сервере с ip для локального подключения всё работает нормально, но при подключении к серверу с внешнего ip ,при генерации pdf файла сервер не реагирует.
Использую Rotativa ,файл создается в памяти(FileStream),Windows Server 2008.

Comment: Проверяйте адрес на который вы хоститесь (listen). Если он локальный - то ясно что снаружи сервер будет не доступен.

Comment: Сервер снаружи доступен,проблема лишь при генерации pdf файла